# Help elect our provisional moderators

Tags: discussion, moderation

According to [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) we should be having a discussion about who our provisional moderators should be.

The primary job of a moderator is **to look at every flagged post, and take action if necessary**. For more information on what purpose moderators serve, see [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) and [Stack Exchange Moderator Elections Begin](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/).

For an example of a previous provisional moderator discussion (and what format the nominations should take), see 
[this post on English Language Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160/select-your-provisional-moderators).

Here are some basic guidelines:

- **Each nomination should be a separate answer.** Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.
  Here is what we are looking for in a Moderator:

We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Bonus points for:

- Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
  Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

Comment: So when are moderators assigned? how long are nominations open for?

Comment: Not sure. I was expecting @RobertCartaino or someone to jump in and close the nominations at some point. I guess they will get there soon.

Comment: This nomination thread is just the first step to gather input and give us a head start. It's not a highly-formal process like the community elections, but we generally start into them about two weeks after the site is created. The total time elapsed depends on how much input we get, how long it takes to get responses to from the candidates, and generally the resources available to coordinate the administrative and technical components. The process is under way now, and an announcement will be posted when the appointments  are complete. Soon.

Answer (score 24):

**[MediaGirl](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/28/mediagirl)** ([meta](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28/mediagirl)) aka Anna Brown - *I accept my self nomination!*

I'm very interested in helping in all ways that I can. A review type responsibility is right up my alley.

Vote for Pedro.

Comment: +1. You have been very supportive of this community right from the start, and put a huge amount of effort into pushing the Area 51 proposal.

Comment: +1 for Anna, she's been instrumental in promoting the site to the community and has been uber-active here.

Comment: +1 for Anna from me too.

Comment: Yep, i'll addd my vote for this. MediaGirl for Presidentess!

Comment: Definitely a vote for Anna, if she wants this responsibility ;) . She's been the absolute sparkplug to get the ExpressionEngine Stack Exchange to exist, and prosper. Mine is a Vote For Pedro.

Comment: +1 Wouldn't have happened without her.

Answer (score 13):

I'd like to also nominate [**Adrian Macneil**](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/150/adrian-macneil) ([meta](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/users/150/adrian-macneil)) *- accepted*

You've been a great supporter of the beta site and have helped us get the site and organization moving forward on the meta site. You also have a clear and fair understanding of the guidelines for questions/answers.

Comment: +1 for Adrian, lots of thought going into answers both in meta and on the main site.

Answer (score 13):

**[Derek Hogue](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/55/derek-hogue)** ([meta](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/users/55/derek-hogue)) *- accepted*

Derek was active on Stack Overflow answering EE questions long before this site started, and has contributed a lot to meta and the main site.

Comment: Glad to accept - though I'm still sub-1000 on rep, so I can't edit answers.

Comment: Eh, you'll get there quickly. :)

Comment: +1 Derek is a pillar.

Comment: I've marked the answers community wiki to avoid the 1000 rep requirement.

Answer (score 8):

I nominate [**Tom Davies**](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/104/tom-davies) ([meta](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/users/104/tom-davies)) - *withdrawn*

He's been very active giving great EE answers, made significant effort to curate and improve content, and has made some great contributions to meta as well.

Comment: With regret, I've decided to withdraw my acceptance of Alex's nomination. I've just accepted a new job that's going to mean I spend less time working with EE from the New Year, as well as having less free time in general. The other proposed moderators are very highly qualified and I'm sure will do a brilliant job, moreover I think they'll be better placed to help guide the site forward over the next few months than I will.

Comment: Congratulations Tom!

Answer (score 7):

**[adrienne](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/139/adrienne)** ([meta](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/users/139/adrienne)) *- accepted*

Adrienne has been around the community a long time, is very knowledgeable about EE, and has contributed a lot so far to both meta and the main site.

Comment: I dunno how to accept, but I accept the nomination.

Comment: I've edited the answer to indicate your acceptance.

Answer (score 7):

**[Sean Smith](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/15/createsean)** ([meta](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15/createsean)) *- accepted*

I nominate Sean to help moderate the site. He's active in the EE community and has done a fast job of building a respectable rep on the SE beta site with good questions and answers.

Answer (score 6):

**[Dom Stubbs](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/77/dom-stubbs)** ([meta](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77/dom-stubbs))

Dom has also been very active in both meta and the main site.

Comment: Presumably we only need a few moderators at this point. I'm sure that all of the current nominees would do a great job and I don't know how much time I can commit, so ideally I'd prefer to take a back seat on this one. Cheers for the consideration though.

Answer (score 6):

[**Natetronn**](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/16/natetronn) ([meta](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16/natetronn))

Also a great candidate for a moderator. He has demonstrated his leadership qualities by providing helpful comments to users (guidance on improving questions) and is a top curator.

Comment: I really appreciate the nomination! Sounds like we only need about 3~ moderators Pro tempore during beta and the nominees that have currently accepted the position are definitely more deserving. I would of course be honored to accept the nomination though, please consider me as a backup at this point if need be :)

Answer (score 5):

[**Justin Kimbrell**](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/101/justin-kimbrell) ([meta](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101/justin-kimbrell)) - *accepted*

I'd like to nominate Justin. He's an extremely talented addon developer who has been putting out great work since finding his feet in the EE community. I can tell from meeting him in person and following him on Twitter that he sincerely enjoys helping people. His answers to-date on the beta site have been highly considered and add ton of value.